# Firebase Cloud Messaging from Console not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It never works when sending to All Users or the entire app or any which way unless I specifically list the device tokens.  I've resorted to using the Test Devices method to send, but that isn't sustainable when my user count goes exponentially.

Any suggestions why FCM works sent to individually listed tokens, but all users, nada?

Comment: Need to see code to help debug code.

Comment: There's no code invovled w FCM console.